# Test never fails - why is Assert not working?

Tags: c#, macos, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to teach myself Selenium with C# and have run into a problem with my assert. This is my code:

```
// Compare Expected Price with Actual Price
string Price = "£29";
IWebElement ProductPrice = driver.FindElement(By.ClassName("search-product-price"));
AssertLibrary.Assert.IsEqual(ProductPrice, Price);
```

The problem is that the test never fails regardless of the price I enter, so obviously the assert is not working

The website I am using to test my code against is https://www.buyagift.co.uk/ so the full test is to go to the url, enter dinner for 2 into the search field and compare the price of the first one returned with the set price.

Comment: Well, `ProductPrice` is an `IWebElement`, and `Price` is a `string`. Why would they be considered equal?

Comment: Need [MCVE] - how would we know how mysterious `AssertLibrary.Assert.IsEqual` compares those two objects of different types?

Answer (score 0):

So you are asserting that a `WebElement` equals a `string`, and that's why it's not working for you. You will want to use `.Text` to get the price contained in the `WebElement`:

```
// Compare Expected Price with Actual Price
string Price = "£29";
IWebElement ProductPrice = driver.FindElement(By.ClassName("search-product-price"));
AssertLibrary.Assert.IsEqual(ProductPrice.Text, Price);
```

But in order to achieve your desired functionality, I think you need to make a few updates to your code to get a list of `WebElement`, pick the `First()`, and check the `.Text` of that element. I also went to your website, searched "Dinner for 2", and your `By.ClassName("search-product-price")` isn't returning any results on the search results page. I could be misunderstanding your example, but I updated your selector to something that works on this page https://www.buyagift.co.uk/Search/Key/dinner%20for%202:

```
string Price = "£29";

var priceText = driver.FindElements(By.XPath("//div[contains(@class, 'currentpricenow')]")).First().Text;

AssertLibrary.Assert.IsEqual(priceText, Price);
```